# How to open project with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

So after writing in a projectfile as in the [cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadproject.html) in QGIS 2.14 with.

```
finfo = QFileInfo(filename)
project.write(finfo)
```

I want to open that project in the main window. So  I try:

```
project.read(finfo)
```

But the project doesn't open.
How can I open the .qgs file I've created in the window?

Comment: Did you close the project before trying to open it? Did you receive errors when running the code?

Comment: I tried with another project open. And with no project open @joseph

Answer (score 5):

It is strange but if you write a project and read directly after the project does not load correctly. You can solve this strange using the `clear()` method, before you read the project file:

**Simple script**

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

project = QgsProject.instance() 
mFile=QFileInfo("C://Users//fran//Desktop//test.qgs")

project.write(mFile)

project.clear()

project.read(mFile)
```

Comment: Is this explained anywhere in the qgis cookbook? Which is the closest thing to a pyqgis api I've been able to find.

Comment: I don't know, I found this solution, observing the method in the qgis core

Comment: Unfortunatley it also clears the project I noticed later so it isn't optimal.

Comment: clears the project??of course,but you load again same project or anyone.